# recursively getting nested comments with laravel eloquent + mongodb

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am creating an comment `resource` in `Laravel` with `MongoDB` as `database`. I followed one [use case](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#one-document-per-comment) of `Laravel website` to model everything.

Now, I want to get a comment and its replies. I thought of doing it with this `code`:

```
public function nested_comments($comment_id){
    $comment = Comment::where('_id', $comment_id)->first();
    $nested_comments = Comment::where('discussion_id', $comment_id)->get();
    $comment->replies = $nested_comments;

    foreach ($nested_comments as $nested) 
    {
        $this->nested_comments($nested->_id);
    }

    return $comment;
}
```

But I only get the comment itself and the first level of related comments. I found some questions on `StackOverflow` with answers, but they are using `Laravel views` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971581/laravel-eloquent-nested-comment-and-replies)) or rearranging all comments ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210874/recursive-children-with-laravel-commentable-nested-set)) and I am actually creating an API.

The Comment `class` is not related with other `classes`, this must be an generic `class` for all Comments in the `system`.

Comment: the answer i add don't need lets say replies to have post_id it just related to the main comment then the main comment is related to what ever model so its ok for a Polymorphic Relationships between main comment and lets say post video report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not make it a self referential relationship

first add parent_id

```
Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
});
```

then in your Comment Model

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment', 'parent_id');
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

so you can do something like this

```
$comments = Comment::with('replies')->get();
```

Comment: it's a cleaner approach, but I am also getting just the first level of comments

Comment: I am trying here, and I found out that to get one more level of comments, I should do this: ->with('replies.replies')->get() and do this over and over again

Comment: well if i commented : nice video and some one replied : no its not nice and another replied : no it is nice you can solve them the way facebook do it ? its not nested in nested its main comment and all replies are children of the main comment on same level

Comment: I found out on laracasts that putting return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id', 'id')->with('replies'); on replies() function I can get the multi-level comments I wanted. Ahmed, thanks for helping me on this ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like following example for selecting blogs and its comments and sub comments ans sub sub comments where the comments are accepted by admin.
your controller:

```
public function show(Blog $blog)
{
    $blog = $blog->with([
        'comments' => function ($query) {
            $query
                ->where([['parent_id', null], ['accepted', 1]])
                ->with(['replies' => function ($q) {
                    $q
                        ->where('accepted', 1)
                        ->with(['sub_reply' => function ($qq) {
                             $qq->where('accepted', 1);
                        }]);
                }]);
        }
    ])->first();
```

and your model:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'blog_id');
}
```